# Imagick: PNG support available in command line, but not available in PHP

Tags: php, image, png, imagick

I found that I did not have PNG support in my Imagick installation, so I installed **libpng**. Now I can see that PNG format is supported when I run a command

```
convert -list format
```

And conversion from PNG to JPG works fine from command line:

```
convert a.png b.jpg
```

But when I try to read a PNG file in PHP:

```
    $src = new \Imagick();
    $src->readImageBlob( file_get_contents($file) ); // reading PNG format
```

-it gives me **Error 500 ("...no decode delegate for this image format")**

Also when I run `phpinfo()` - I see no PNG in list of Imagick's supported file formats. There are many others, but no PNG.

I tried to I resintall PHP Imagick driver and then restart apache - still no succeess.

PS: I have PHP 5.4 @ CentOS

Comment: What's the result of `identify a.png` on your shell?

Comment: a.png PNG 24x24 24x24+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used a guide for Imagick installation @CentOS from the link below, reinstalled **everything** exactly as it said there, and it helped - http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44449&page=1

Answer (score 1):

According to the installation requirements. "The amount of formats supported is by Imagick is entirely dependent upon the amount of formats supported by your ImageMagick installation."  I imagine you’ll need to rebuild the PHP imagemagick extension. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: I've already tried to re-intall PHP Imagick extension ( imagick-3.1.0RC2 ), restarted apache - and nothing has changed. Do I miss something? Do I have to add some commands after ./configure to add PNG support?

Comment: `./configure --help` to see what options are available to you. You might need to do something like `./configure --with-png=yes`