# Error when resizing an upload image using PHP ImageMagick in Windows but not in Centos

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to resize an image from upload using PHP ImageMagick class. I successfully resize the image upload using `exec` PHP function in my development machine (Windows 10):

```
$tmpFile = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
$move_uploadFile = $upload_path . $_FILES["upload"]['name'];
exec("magick $tmpFile -thumbnail 800x $move_uploadFile");
```

The problem is my production machine's configuration (Centos 7) doesn't allow using `exec` function. Therefore, I use the code below:

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick($tmpFile);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$im->thumbnailImage(800, null);
$im->writeImage($move_uploadFile);
```

And I get this error message:

```
Error when creating a thumbnail: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501
```

As far as I know this kind of error relates because image type delegate libraries is unavailable, but when the image resize using `exec` function success, I think this is not the case.

Edit: I ran this code on my production machine, and it worked! I'm happy but I can't understand why on my Windows machine the code didn't work, but it work on Centos 7.

Anyone knows what the problem is to why it doesn't work at Windows but work on Centos?

Comment: The ImageMagick libraries compiled into your PHP are not necessarily identical with the executable you have on the command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968345/imagick-png-support-available-in-command-line-but-not-available-in-php